# How to get all users application data folders under system account?

Tags: c#

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` returns current user folder, but under system account it returns for example:

```
C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\
```

So the question is how to get all users' *AppData* folders by using the system account?

Comment: Explain what you want to do, not how you think you should do that.

Comment: I want to get all appData folders paths for all users

Comment: Yes it is clear from your question that you want that. It is a weird question though, that's why I ask **why you want to do that**.

Comment: Why would you ever need to do that?

Comment: We're trying to get you to elaborate on what you're planning to *do* with this information once you've obtained it. Presumably, the entire purpose of your code isn't just to set a string equal to a particular folder path and then exit?

Comment: agree, all of the folders is superfluous, only current user but from system account

Answer (score 0):

I think, this could help you :

```
//List all the users
List<String> usersList = new List<String>();
ManagementObjectSearcher sidQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Account");
ManagementObjectCollection results = sidQuery.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject result in results)
{
   usersList.Add(result["Name"])
}

//Showing all the partitions letters 
String[] strDrives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives();
Foreach (string strDrive in strDrives)
{
  //Check if profil has AppData folder
  List<String> usersAppData = new List<String>();
  String pathAppData = String.Empty;
  foreach(String user in usersList)
  {
     pathAppData = String.Format("{0}\Users\{1}\AppData", strDrive, user);
     if(Directory.Exists(pathAppData ))
     {
        usersAppData.Add(pathAppData);
     }
  }
}

    //Here, you've got all the users AppData folder in usersAppData
```

Comment: Environment.SystemDrive not work, the folder can be moved to any drive

Comment: "SystemRoot" also not work, it's just windows not user's folder

Comment: Yes this will work but it's to slow especial in case of network drives

Comment: I modified the code. Code list every partitions, and check for all.
"SystemRoot" was a mistake : Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot")

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I wanted to get the paths to the user special folders(Desktop or MyDocuments) under "SYSTEM" account. After lengthy investigations, I found the solution:

```
string sid = string.Empty; 
using (var mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                        "Select SID From Win32_UserAccount where Disabled = 0"))
{
    foreach (var bios in mos.Get())
    {
        sid = bios["SID"].ToString();
    }
}
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.Users.OpenSubKey(sid +
@"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"))
{
    var docFolder = key.GetValue("Personal");
    var desktopFolder = key.GetValue("Desktop");
    Console.WriteLine("document folder: {0}", docFolder);
    Console.WriteLine("Desktop folder: {0}", desktopFolder);
}
```

"Disabled = 0" is option to get active user. If you open your registry using "regedit" you will find all you need.

Comment: Hi, where from you accessed this method ManagementObjectSearcher() ? are you accessing any library like win32 ?